tinymce duplica textarea en formulario livewire!
Tengo este codigo donde lo que hago es insertar un editor tinymce para editar y formatear el contenido a html, en el codigo como se puede ver, estoy utilizando tinymce desde un cdn, y el problema es que por alguna razon me duplica el al agregar en el selector: 'textarea#mensaje'
asi tengo mi codigo!
<div>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        @livewireStyles

        <title>CKE5 in Laravel</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/myapikey/tinymce/7/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <x-app-layout>
        <x-slot name="header">
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">
                {{ __('Envio de publicidad') }}
            </h2>
        </x-slot>

        <div class="py-2">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        <div class="sm:flex sm:items-center">
                            <div class="sm:flex-auto">
                                <h1 class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Envio de publicidad masiva</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mt-8 flow-root">
                            <div class=" mx-auto p-6 bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg">
                                <form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="space-y-4">
                                    <!-- Campo de Asunto -->
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="asunto" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Asunto</label>
                                        <input id="asunto" type="text" wire:model="asunto" required
                                            class="mt-1 block w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                                            placeholder="Asunto del correo">
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Campo de Mensaje (WYSIWYG) -->
                                    <div wire:ignore>
                                        <label for="mensaje" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Mensaje</label>
                                        <textarea id="mensaje" required class="mt-1 size-72 block w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">

                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Campo de Correos -->
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="correos" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Correos a enviar</label>
                                        <input
                                            id="correos"
                                            type="text"
                                            wire:model="correos"
                                            required
                                            class="mt-1 block w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                                            placeholder="ejemplo1@correo.com, ejemplo2@correo.com">
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Campo de Adjunto -->
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="adjunto" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Adjunto</label>
                                        <input
                                            id="adjunto"
                                            type="file"
                                            wire:model="adjunto"
                                            class="mt-1 block w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Botón de Envío -->
                                    <div>
                                        <button
                                            type="submit"
                                            class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                            Enviar Correos
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                                <!-- Mensaje de Confirmación -->
                                @if (session()->has('message'))
                                    <div class="mt-4 p-4 bg-green-100 text-green-800 rounded-lg">
                                        {{ session('message') }}
                                    </div>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </x-app-layout>

    @livewireScripts
    </body>
</div>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea#mensaje",
        plugins: [
            // Core editing features
            'anchor', 'autolink', 'charmap', 'codesample', 'emoticons', 'image', 'link', 'lists', 'media', 'searchreplace', 'table', 'visualblocks', 'wordcount',
            // Your account includes a free trial of TinyMCE premium features
            // Try the most popular premium features until Oct 26, 2024:
            'checklist', 'mediaembed', 'casechange', 'export', 'formatpainter', 'pageembed', 'a11ychecker', 'tinymcespellchecker', 'permanentpen', 'powerpaste', 'advtable', 'advcode', 'editimage', 'advtemplate', 'mentions', 'tableofcontents', 'footnotes', 'mergetags', 'autocorrect', 'typography', 'inlinecss', 'markdown',
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table mergetags | addcomment showcomments | spellcheckdialog a11ycheck typography | align lineheight | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',

        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                // Aquí sincronizamos el contenido del editor con Livewire
                @this.set('mensaje', editor.getContent());
            });
        }
    });
</script>

En el script crea la relación usando el selector y pareciera que algo ahi me genera problema o bien lo otro tendria que ver con la carga de livewire por algo que leia por ahi pero no se que tanto sentido tenga esto...
alguna idea para poder solucionar el problema? Gracias!
